# SPO Rest API call to break inheritance on folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

So I am making calls to the SPO end points to break inheritance on a folder in a document library. I keep getting either 400 BAD Request responses, 403 or 500's. Am I calling the right end point? I've not used the SPO rest end points that much and used to SharePoint 2003.

Below are the responses I am getting from the REST endpoints, the 403 confuses me since I have an authorization token (bearer) and providing X-RequestDigest header entry on the request.

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Active/Folder')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  X-SharePointHealthScore: 3
  X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
  DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0
  SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 13
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  SPRequestGuid: bd8f309f-3086-9000-7e9b-25aacb50e886
  request-id: bd8f309f-3086-9000-7e9b-25aacb50e886
  MS-CV: nzCPvYYwAJB+myWqy1Dohg.0
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.19527
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
  X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 675FB16933E944B1B1B14158E0A2BBC7 Ref B: BN3EDGE0209 Ref C: 2020-01-30T14:15:58Z
  Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:15:58 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 14:15:58 GMT
  Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:15:58 GMT
}}




https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Active/Folder')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)

{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  X-SharePointHealthScore: 7
  X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
  DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0
  SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 35
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  SPRequestGuid: f28f309f-b0ca-9000-7eb6-34e85d5af3e4
  request-id: f28f309f-b0ca-9000-7eb6-34e85d5af3e4
  MS-CV: nzCP8sqwAJB+tjToXVrz5A.0
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.19527
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
  X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 1A80F24EC6F74635A908DB7CFACA11DE Ref B: BN3EDGE0721 Ref C: 2020-01-30T14:19:36Z
  Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:19:36 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 14:19:36 GMT
  Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:19:36 GMT
}}



https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Active/Folder')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  X-SharePointHealthScore: 6
  X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
  X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
  DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0
  SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 203
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  SPRequestGuid: 2390309f-c0f4-9000-829c-be3643d73354
  request-id: 2390309f-c0f4-9000-829c-be3643d73354
  MS-CV: nzCQI/TAAJCCnL42Q9czVA.0
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.19527
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
  X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: FE343F1A8715425AA3E05E171876D047 Ref B: BN3EDGE0220 Ref C: 2020-01-30T14:22:58Z
  Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:22:58 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 14:22:58 GMT
  Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 14:22:58 GMT
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think possibly you have the wrong value for the *server* relative URL.  You showed as an example the endpoint you are hitting at:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/_api
```

A "server relative" URL would in that case start at `/sites/`.  By putting just `'/Active/Folder'` as the server relative URL, you are telling SharePoint to look for it here:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/Active/Folder
```

which I think is not really where it is.  You probably want your server relative URL for the folder to be:

```
/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/Active/Folder
```

or

```
/sites/xxxx-QA/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/Lists/Active/Folder
```

or whatever it is.  The point being that it should be the URL starting from all the way back at `/sites/`

Comment: Oh my goodness, that was a total brain moment. Thank you sir! That was it. I am getting a X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656 now, but I know how to fix that! Thank you!